# Ajax multi request on WCF handled synchronously instead of asynchronously

Tags: c#, ajax, multithreading, wcf, session

hope it will be simple for you guys to help me out with this issue :)

I have a WCF service somewhere in the cloud, working fine. I am using a PerCall and Single, nothing especially different than a regular wcf.

my problem is the following :

When using a web client (ajax for instance) to send http GET requests, the treatment of the requests doesn't react in the manner I wanted to. Let me explain my point with a short code :

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class Api
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "api/Function1", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public String Function1()
    {
        logMessage("Function1 -> Begin on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        logMessage("Function1 -> End on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return "Function1 done";
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "api/Function2", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public String Function2()
    {
        logMessage("Function2 -> Begin on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        logMessage("Function2 -> End on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return "Function2 done";
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "api/Function3", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public String Function3()
    {
        logMessage("Function3 -> Begin on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        logMessage("Function3 -> End on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return "Function3 done";
    }
}
```

and the client code:

```
var json1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
json1.open("GET", "127.0.0.1:81/api/Function1", true);
json1.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
json1.onload = function (e) {
  alert("function1 done");
}
var json2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
json2.open("GET", "127.0.0.1:81/api/Function2", true);
json2.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
json2.onload = function (e) {
  alert("function2 done");
}
var json3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
json3.open("GET", "127.0.0.1:81/api/Function3", true);
json3.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
json3.onload = function (e) {
  alert("function3 done");
}
json1.send(NULL);
json2.send(NULL);
json3.send(NULL);
```

I have multiples functions in this WCF that I wanted to be treated asynchronously when I call them. Each of those have a 3 seconds thread sleep for the tests.

Because I'm sending my 3 requests asynchronously from my web client, I am supposed to be waiting 3 seconds and receive all the responses at the same time (If it was really asynchronously, as it is supposed to be treated on different threads).

From what I already read on the net, when sending a request to a WCF service, it stored in the session an ID, that will be the same for each http request sended from that same session. If the session is the same, the treatment will be done on the same thread, one request after another one, like a FIFO. To be sure that the problem is because of the session, I tried to send those request from 2 differents browsers (chrome and firefox) at the same time, and it works fine (by fine, I mean that the request are handled on 2 differents threads). Here are the logs of the test for one session:

```
10:50:00 - Log service - Function1 on thread 9 -> Begin
10:50:03 - Log service - Function1 on thread 9 -> End
10:50:03 - Log service - Function2 on thread 9 -> Begin
10:50:06 - Log service - Function2 on thread 9 -> End
10:50:06 - Log service - Function3 on thread 9 -> Begin
10:50:09 - Log service - Function3 on thread 9 -> End
```

And here are the logs for 2 sessions at the same time :

```
10:50:00 - Log service - Function 1 on thread 9 -> Begin
10:50:00 - Log service - Function 1 on thread 10 -> Begin
10:50:03 - Log service - Function 1 on thread 9 -> End
10:50:03 - Log service - Function 1 on thread 10 -> End

10:50:03 - Log service - Function 2 on thread 9 -> Begin
10:50:03 - Log service - Function 2 on thread 10 -> Begin
10:50:06 - Log service - Function 2 on thread 9 -> End
10:50:06 - Log service - Function 2 on thread 10 -> End

10:50:06 - Log service - Function 3 on thread 9 -> Begin
10:50:06 - Log service - Function 3 on thread 10 -> Begin
10:50:09 - Log service - Function 3 on thread 9 -> End
10:50:09 - Log service - Function 3 on thread 10 -> End
```

And this is what I'm waiting for one session :

```
    10:50:00 - Log service - Function 1 on thread 9 -> Begin
    10:50:00 - Log service - Function 2 on thread 10 -> Begin
    10:50:00 - Log service - Function 3 on thread 11 -> Begin

    10:50:03 - Log service - Function 1 on thread 9 -> End
    10:50:03 - Log service - Function 2 on thread 10 -> End
    10:50:03 - Log service - Function 3 on thread 11 -> End
```

Any ideas to solve that issue without disable session? I hope I'm clear enought to everyone, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this behavior change if you specify `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple`?

Comment: I tried several changes, as multiple instead of single, PerSession instead of PerCall, adding a few things, but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you also tried running it outside ASP.NET, as self-hosted WCF service?

Comment: I didn't, but working with ios and android clients (because there is no session setted once again)

Comment: I'd still try self-hosting, just to make sure I'd be seeing the same behavior as with ASP.NET host: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: All right, exactly same thing with same configuration :(